# How to resolve win32com error with xl.Visible=True?

Tags: python, win32com

Whenever I execute

```
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
```

together, I get an error. But the error doesn't appear if I execute line by line

```
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

then

xl.Visible = True
```

Error:

```
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-ea9dc88dd3f0>", line 2, in <module>
    xl.Visible = True

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 565, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146777998), None)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

win32com is poorly documented, so I wouldn't put it past them to have a few bugs, too.

I just checked, because I have a script that uses win32com as well, and I cannot reproduce your issue, but my Dispatch is different:

```
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

Maybe give that a try. Not sure what the differences are exactly. Are you Py2 or 3?